# From Chemical Engineering undergrad to chemistry graduate school

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, engineering, chemistry

Right now I'm studying Chemical Engineering My CGPA is 3.4 and I'm a junior.
I'm thinking about joining a chemistry graduate program after a graduate.

So my question is if I applied will they look at my chemical engineering core GPA or only science subjects GPA?

and as an international student if my CGPA was around 3.5 where can i apply in USA, CANADA , UK ?

THANKS

Comment: What is your GPA out of? Some schools in Canada use a A+ = 4.0 maximum scale while others use a A+ = 4.3 scale. Also, the country that you took your degree in is relevant because at Canadian universities they use special formulas to convert international grades.

Comment: It is out of 4.0.  and I didn't take my undergrad in Canada unfortunately.         I have a question if you don't mind, when u took the science program did they require you to take extra undergraduate science courses?

Comment: I took an engineering program in my undergrad and I am taking "Applied Science" for my master's program. We call engineering research "applied science" here in Canada so I wasn't changing fields. It is possible that you might not have the right background courses but that should be evaluated by the people receiving your application. They will let you know if you need to take some undergrad courses to catch up. Although I imagine with a ChemEng background it won't be difficult to transfer to ChemSci. In fact I know someone who went from a ChemSci undergrad to a ChemEng master's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a Canadian graduate student in Applied Science with an undergraduate in Engineering so my answer comes from some personal experience.

What I've always been told is that your grades from relevant courses in the most recent two years of university are the most important when considering you for acceptance into a program. So if you apply for a BSc in Chemistry, your Chemical engineering courses should be considered relevant, but any non-technical electives would not.

In most Canadian graduate schools you are expected to maintain an average above B+ (3.3 out of 4.3 maximum). Depending on the scale used to determine your CGPA you might be just above that threshold, which makes your GPA respectable but not stellar.

You can apply to any university you like, they won't turn away your application. Make sure to check out the [U15](http://u15.ca/) Universities if you plan on applying in Canada. They are generally considered the most respected universities in the country.

If you have any co-op work terms/summer terms remaining before you graduate, and if you are a student at a Canadian university, you should consider applying for an [NSERC Undergraduate Student Research Award](http://www.nserc-crsng.gc.ca/Students-Etudiants/UG-PC/USRA-BRPC_eng.asp). This will get you some research experience in your undergrad that will help you stand out on a grad school application regardless of your GPA.